# Do Webparts get added to the the automatically on deployment?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a webpart in a sharepoint, tried googiling how the webpart would need to be added to the webpart gallery but couldn't find a good answer or a "how to" how it is done programatically through the activateFeature?. is there an online source which I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully clear on your question. Going on an assumption you have developed a webpart using Visual Studio (say 2010 or 2012), then the addition of your webpart to the webpart gallery of your site collection will be taken care of when the solution (the compiled WSP) is deployed (whether you do it through Visual Studio deploy commands, PowerShell etc.) to your target SharePoint instance. If this is not your question, then let us know.